# jasper report height

Tags: jasper-reports, report

I am creating a jasper report. The default size of the report is A4. I want to change the report's height dynamically. I am using HTML Export.So it is creating a html for A4 size(Even though content size is half of the A4 size). If the report content size is small, I want the html page size also small.

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: doesn't that happen automatically? Or there is big white gap at the bottom of the page?

Comment: There is a big white gap in bottom of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the contents `Position type` to `Float` in the elements properties.